# Get big pictures for graph object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can I get a big picture for graph objects?

Example:

```
//take id,name,picture,description from pages, that I like:

http://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?fields=id,name,picture,description&access_token=[token]
```

But how to get **big** picture of all these pages in one query? Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so essentially, you don't need to request the image at all.   Once you have the `object_id`, and you want  to display a large picture, all you have to do is use this URL -

```
https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/picture?type=large
```

I don't store any profile picture URL's anymore, all I have to do is know the user/page_id and I have access to the profile picture via that `object_id`.

For an `<img>` element, just place the URL in the `src` attribute -

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/picture?type=large" />
```

Comment: i don't understand, is this a redirect URL? so, if i want to display a user picture, i need to know his id and just to add (suppose, i have a `PictureBoxObject`) `PictureBoxObject.UrlToImage="https://graph.facebook.com/thisUserId/picture?type=large&access_token=[xxx]"`?

Comment: @lol - Exactly, that URL will return the actual large image.  All you need to do is load the image that the URL returns...

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying.... "`i can't get of this image`" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: sorry, i can't get URL of this image, that returned in your example?

Comment: That URL will give you the image... if you want the direct link to the image you'll have to request it specifically with more than one call to the API.  If I may ask; Why do you need the direct URL?

Comment: oh, i think, that it is simple to get direct URL to image, but, ok, will change some code, thanks!

Comment: It will not get the image, it is for profile picture'

Comment: @VineeshTP - This URL will provide the profile image equivalent for any graph object. Take this event for example - https://graph.facebook.com/328804572620/picture

Comment: Can i get timeline photos ?

Comment: by using this Can I get the timeline photos

Comment: @VineeshTP - if you have an object_id of the feed story - and it's a public post, then it should work.

Comment: Can you post the ID you're trying to use?